# Web-Eid and the Belgian eID

Tags: native, smartcard, web-extension, eid

I am a student and I'm in internship.

Here is the project we are working for :
On a web application, we need the user to authenticate and signing documents with his/her Belgian eID.
We think of using a web extension and a middleware with native messaging.

Ideally, we want a free solution. We find the Web-Eid project from Estonian eID which is opensource, but not yet compatible with Belgian eID.
I tried the ASP.NET example available in GitHub : https://github.com/web-eid/web-eid-asp-dotnet-example

After some changes in the certificates folders, I can authenticate but not signing the document.
When I tried to sign the text on the second webpage, here is the error I got :

> Authentication failed
>
> [Code]  ERR_WEBEID_NATIVE_FATAL
>
> [Message] SHA-384 hash must be 48 bytes long, but is 32 instead in
> src\controller\command-handlers\sign.cpp:154:validateAndStoreDocHashAndHashAlgo

After some searches, I understand that this error is in the middleware ( https://github.com/web-eid/web-eid-app/blob/main/src/controller/command-handlers/sign.cpp ).
I supposed that is because the Estonian sign certificates are in SHA-512 but Belgian ones are in SHA-256.

I thought of modify the middleware of Estonian eID by Belgian one, but I can't find how to do it. I don't really know if it is possible and if it's a good idea...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you share your project please?

Comment: I managed to get it working [here](https://github.com/MintPlayer/MintPlayer.Dotnet.Tools/tree/master/Beid/DemoWebApp)

Answer (score 0):

There is a BeID middleware, I never tried it but they announced

- Communicate with secure websites that require eID authentication
- Sign documents and emails using your eID

https://github.com/Fedict/eid-mw

Comment: I tried this but there is not front-end solution as the estonian.
For our project, we need a front-end since the project is a web application. 

I thought of change the link from the webextension to the middleware of belgian middleware, but I didn't know how to do it.